# catkin_make repeatedly cmakes

Tags: catkin-make, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Previously whenever I changed source code and ran catkin_make again, it would only compile the source files. I don't know where or what changed exactly, but nowadays it will run CMake every time I try to compile (increasing compilation time a lot).

Any idea how I can debug why it is running cmake again every time? Or perhaps why it is doing that?

Best regards,
Hans

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206066/catkin_make-repeatedly-cmakes/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As `catkin` wraps CMake, it should be possible to use 'all' the debug options `cmake` supports ('all' is in quotes, as it's not a lot). From the `cmake` [manpage](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html) (this is for 3.0, but it's mostly the same for older versions):

```
-Wdev
    Enable developer warnings.
    Enable warnings that are meant for the author of the CMakeLists.txt files.

--debug-output
    Put cmake in a debug mode.
    Print extra stuff during the cmake run like stack traces with message(send_error )
    calls.

--trace
    Put cmake in trace mode.
    Print a trace of all calls made and from where with message(send_error ) calls.
```

Pass these either with `--cmake-args ..` through `catkin_make`, or do a `mkdir build; cd build; cmake --DEBUG-OPTION ../src` (the latter does not use Catkin, so you could use that to see whether `catkin` itself is perhaps doing something different / unexpected).

PS: afaik, CMake employs a system similar to plain `make` for checking whether it should re-run it's configuration step. The last time a `CMakeLists.txt` was changed is a factor in this. If filesystem timestamps are 'somehow' not in sync with your local system clock (ie: they are 'from the future'), I think CMake would keep rerunning its configuration step at each invocation. I can't think of a way where that would happen with *each* invocation though (unless someone/something is changing the clock all the time).

The above is probably not happening on your system, but I wanted to mention it just in case.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1